# A pandas-y way to do simple calculations on rows selected from DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd

boxes = {'Color': ['Green','Green','Green','Blue','Blue','Red','Red','Red'],
         'Shape': ['Rectangle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Square','Square','Square','Rectangle'],
         'Price': [10,15,5,5,10,15,15,5]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(boxes, columns= ['Color','Shape','Price'])
```

How do I find the average price of every color (ignoring shape) without for-loops? Or the difference between the maximum and minimum price of every color?

In short, I want the following outcome:

```
        Mean    Range
Green   10.00   10
Blue    7.50    5
Red     11.67   10
```

This example has only three colors, but if we had 1000 colors, is the method still the same/the most efficient one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following :

```py
df = df.groupby('Color').agg([np.mean, np.ptp])
df.columns = ['Mean', 'Range']
```

And you will get the expected result.

Pandas groupby can use multiple aggregation functions. The easiest way to proceed is by using dataframes' native functions such as `.mean()` or `.max()`. One can also use `.agg()`and pass an array of functions to apply such as numpy functions, or even lambda function.

Comment: 'Price' isn't specified in the first line of your code. Does python work on the first column that yields a meaningful result (i.e. the column with numbers in it)? How does it find what we want?

Comment: @NewbieAF It will apply the given aggregation functions on all columns with numerical data. If you had two different Price columns, you would have obtained a multiIndex. Lets say you had Price_A and Price B, then you would get columns ('Mean', 'Price_A'), ('Mean, 'Price_B'), ('Range', 'Price_A') and ('Range', 'Price_B').
The renaming of the columns would slightly differ though. Try it yourself :)

Comment: Is there a way to specify the column in the case of multiple columns with numerical data? If there were Price_A and Price_B, just do it for Price_B?

Comment: You can do it by passing a dict to agg(). This dict will detail aggregation functions to be applied. In you example, it would be .agg({'Price_B': [np.mean, np.ptp]})

Comment: This way, you can also apply different aggregation functions to different columns. For example: 
.agg({'Price_1':[np.mean, np.ptp], 'Price_2':[np.min]})

Answer (score 0):

[Groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the `color` column, get the aggregates, and for the range, get the difference between the `max` and `min`

```
result = (df.groupby("Color")
          .agg(["mean","max","min"])
          .droplevel(0,axis=1)
           #access the max column with brackets
           #rather than dot access
           #as it is a built-in function
          .assign(Range= lambda x: x['max'] - x['min'],
                  mean = lambda x: x['mean'].round(2)
                 )
          .iloc[:,[0,-1]]
         )

result

        mean  Range
Color       
Blue    7.50    5
Green   10.00   10
Red     11.67   10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
g = df.groupby('Color')['Price']
df = pd.concat([g.mean(), g.max() - g.min()], axis=1)
df.columns = ['Mean', 'Range']
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            Mean  Range
Color                  
Blue    7.500000      5
Green  10.000000     10
Red    11.666667     10
```